# Data grid set row style on mouse over

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am working on a C# WPF project and I am having an issue with setting the row colour within the data grid when the mouse is hovering over the row and then reset the row back to how it was before the mouse over.

When I try add the style trigger to the XAML I then get an exception thrown.

Below is the XAML code

```
<UserControl x:Class="ReportReader.UserControls.ReportViewer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="1024" d:DesignHeight="800" xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Report for..." Margin="12,12,12,0" Name="lblReportDateTitle" FontSize="26" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Height="44" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,62,0,0" Name="cboRegisteredApps" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="202" SelectionChanged="cboRegisteredApps_SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Select App" IsSelected="True" />
        </ComboBox>
        <DataGrid RowStyle="{StaticResource gridCellStyle}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="14,415,12,12" Name="dataExceptionGroups" IsReadOnly="True" ColumnWidth="*">

        </DataGrid>
        <chartingToolkit:Chart DataContext="1,10 2,20 3,30 4,40" Margin="0,118,12,0" Name="chartExceptionStatusPieGraph" Title="Chart Title" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="408" Height="291" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <chartingToolkit:PieSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
        </chartingToolkit:Chart>
    </Grid>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="gridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

Below is the exception that I get

> 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an
>   exception.' Line number '11' and line position '110'.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML is parsed from top to bottom and all `StaticResource` references are resolved at runtime while loading XAML. But resource `gridCellStyle` is defined below its usage that's why parser is unable to locate resource.

Either move the style before its usage (`declare resources before userControl content`) -

```
<UserControl>
   <UserControl.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="gridCellStyle">...</Style>
   </UserControl.Resources>
   <Grid>...</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Or use `DynamicResource` in case resource is defined below its usage -

```
<DataGrid RowStyle="{DynamicResource gridCellStyle}">
```

Comment: Glad to help Boardy :)